# How to perform search multiple times in ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, list, search, expandablelistview

For now I'm using this algorithm:

```
List<String> constantListDataHeader = playersNames;
String[] listDataHeaderArray = new String[listDataHeader.size()];
playersNames.toArray(listDataHeaderArray);
...
EditText textsearch = view.findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
textsearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                            for (String item : listDataHeaderArray) {
                                if (item.toLowerCase().contains(textsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase())) {
                                } else {
                                    listDataHeader.remove(item);
                                }
                            }
                                return false;

                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

The problem is the fact that if I try to perform search one more time, it won't work because the `listDataHeader` will consist of suitable for the previous search items only (`listDataHeader.remove`). Are there any other ways to perform search if I need it to work multiple times?

Comment: You should perform the search on the full list, but display only the results. So basically you need one copy of the full dataset where you search and one copy for the results. After each search is changed, you can clear the results copy.

Comment: @peshkira yes, I've thought about it, but here comes a new problem. I do search in editableListDataHeader and put the result into listDataHeader which is a list of my adapter. But when I want to do something like `editableListDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>(constantListDataHeader)` I get something like "Variable 'editableListDataHeader' is accessed from within inner class". And I can't make it static as well. I can give you full code to make it clear

Comment: @peshkira well, I finally managed to do it by changing this code to `editableListDataHeader.clear()
                            for(String item2 : constantListDataHeader){
                                editableListDataHeader.add(item2);
                            }` and setting it right after `if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {`. Thank you!